# Condition vs Semaphore in java concurrency

Tags: java, conditional-statements, semaphore

I'm having trouble getting my head around a homework problem. The question asks us to mimic the implementation of Condition by only using Semaphore as a concurrency control class and nothing else. Can someone point me in a direction by explaining exactly what the question is getting at

> In the example MySemaphore.java, we implemented a Semaphore using Lock
>   and Condition. Now, still keeping in the same spirit, implement a
>   class MyCondition that works like Condition with methods await and
>   signal (no need to implement the rest of the methods here). In your
>   implementation, the only concurrency control class that you are
>   allowed to use is Semaphore.

Here's the example referred to in the question

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

// A standard exercise of Concurrency 101 is to show that Semaphores are
// equivalent to Locks and Condition Variables in power, by implementing
// one with the other. Here, a simple Semaphore implementation.

public class MySemaphore {
    private int permits;
    private Lock mutex;
    private Condition permitAvailable;

    public MySemaphore(int permits, boolean fair) {
        this.permits = permits;
        this.mutex = new ReentrantLock(fair);
        this.permitAvailable = mutex.newCondition();
    }

    public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
        mutex.lock();
        try {
            while(permits < 1) {
                // Wait for one permit to become available.
                permitAvailable.await();
            }
            permits--;
        }
        // Ensure that mutex is unlocked even if an exception is thrown.
        finally { mutex.unlock(); }
    }

    public void release() {
        mutex.lock();
        permits++;
        // One waiting thread can now acquire a permit.
        permitAvailable.signal();
        mutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your homework, check source code of Lock & Condition & Semaphore of j2se first.
Then try implement it, in that way your homework make sense, it make you understand the mechanism.